# finding the value of the min and max pixel

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, colors

I computed the smallest and largest pixel values for pixel in a grayscale image as follows:

```
smallest = numpy.amin(image)
biggest = numpy.amax(image)
```

but this will only works in grayscale.

How can I do the same for a color image (RGB)?

Comment: Yes it works, use numpy.min and numpy.max

Comment: smallest = numpy.min(img)
biggest = numpy.max(img)   like this? how do i use it on an image in RGB mode?

Comment: Indeed that return only one value, I am looking for a solution

Answer (score 21):

You can access each channel with the slices as follows:

```
# red
image[..., 0].min()
image[..., 0].max()
# green
image[..., 1].min()
image[..., 1].max()
# blue
image[..., 2].min()
image[..., 2].max()
```

Comment: this give me en error                                               Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    minred = im[..., 0].min()
TypeError: 'JpegImageFile' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @Mumfordwiz - You need to convert whatever you're using into a numpy array.  Apparently it's a `JpegImageFile` (not sure which library that's from).  If the `JpegImageFile` class supports it, you may just be able to do `data = np.array(image)`.

Comment: @Mumfordwiz right, so you're reading the image using PIL / Pillow. As Joe Kington says you will be able to convert to a Numpy array with `np.array(image)`

Answer (score 3):

You can test it quickly in python script.

```
import numpy
img = numpy.zeros((10,10,3), dtype=numpy.int)  # Black RGB image (10x10)
img[5,2] = [255, 255, 255]
print img.reshape((img.shape[0]*img.shape[1], 3)).max(axis=0)
```

> array([255, 255, 255])

Comment: ok this seems to work, but I don't understand how to use it, and find each min and max value in each color

Comment: @Mumfordwiz - What do you mean by "get each value"?  Do you just want `red, green, blue = result`?  Also, which axis to use (the `axis=0` argument) will depend on how your array is ordered.

Comment: I'm trying to get each color's max and min value. and I can't  seem to get how to use this

Comment: @Mumfordwiz - The array that's returned is the maximum red value, the maximum green value, and the maximum blue value. (Though the bands might be in a different order depending on the library you're using, etc.)  To get the minimum values, just use `min(axis=0)` instead of `max`.

Answer (score 3):

```
smallest = image.min(axis=(0, 1))

largest = image.max(axis=(0, 1))
```

are the most syntactically neat imo. The most popular suggestions here are awful.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a BGR image (loaded using OpenCV), I found a simple way to do this:

```
import numpy as np

max_channels = np.amax([np.amax(img[:,:,0]), np.amax(img[:,:,1]), np.amax(img[:,:,2])])

print(max_channels)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy
img = numpy.zeros((10,10,3), dtype=numpy.int)  
img[5,2] = [255, 255, 255]
print img.reshape((img.shape[0]*img.shape[1], 3)).max(axis=0)
```

Comment: Adding some explanation would make this answer more useful.

Comment: This is the part of review answer in stackoverflow. Add some explanation though code is explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results as arrays, this is a simple solution:

```
smallest = np.amin(image, axis=(0, 1))
largest = np.amax(image, axis=(0, 1))
```

But for some reason these are faster:

```
smallest = image.min(axis=0).min(axis=0)
biggest = image.max(axis=0).max(axis=0)
```

If you want the results as lists, just add `.tolist()` to the end of each above.