# How can i extract out the coordinates (top, bottom, left, right) of white mask (polygon) in image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to extract out the coordinates (x, y) of binary image. I need the top, bottom, left right (x, y) points of the white mask which is i guess is polygon. The image shown below , how can i take out the points ?

Image:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDScX.png)

I am doing but it is giving me array of coordinates:

**My code:**

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2 

img = cv2.imread('Image.png')

x, y = np.where(img==(255,255))
points = list(zip(x,y))
print(points)
```

Comment: see np.amax() and np.amin()

Comment: @fmw42, Could you please post your code as opinion, I think i am doing wrong

Comment: Post your attempt. Then others can suggest corrections.

Comment: @fmw42, Yes I have posted

Comment: I do not see where you used np.amin() and np.amax()?  But why can you not just get the cv2.boundingRect() on the points or the convex hull of the points and compute the min and max points from that?

Comment: I have not used , how can i get the bounding box coordinates ?

Comment: You can also get the contour of the mask and from that get the boundingRect()

Comment: Search Google for examples.  cv2.boundingRect(points) for get the convex hull of the points and do the boundingRect on that. Or get the contour of your mask and do the boundingRect on that.

Comment: See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga103fcbda2f540f3ef1c042d6a9b35ac7 for cv2.boundingRect(). It returns x,y,w,h for the bounding rectangle.  Where x,y is min point and x+w-1,y+h-1 is max point.

Comment: From Google: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117415/finding-the-value-of-the-min-and-max-pixel and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-maximum-and-minimum-element-in-a-numpy-array/

Comment: x, y = np.where(img==(255,255)) should be x, y = np.where(img==(255,255,255)).  Images are 3 channels not 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two simple ways by getting the extreme points for the white blob in your image in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('white_blob.png')

# Method 1: bounding rect

# threshold on white
lower =(255,255,255)
upper = (255,255,255)
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# get points
points = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh.transpose() > 0))
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(points)
print(x,y,w,h)
min = (x,y)
max = (x+w-1,y+h-1)
print("min:", min)
print("max:", max)

# Method 2: Numpy
(Note: Numpy coordinates are y,x. So need to rearrange)

a = np.where(img != 0)
x1,y1,x2,y2 = np.min(a[1]), np.min(a[0]), np.max(a[1]), np.max(a[0])
min = (x1,y1)
max = (x2,y2)
print("min:", min)
print("max:", max)
```

Both methods produce (x,y):

```
min: (0, 293)
max: (127, 363)
```